# :not(:placeholder-shown) is not working with Adjacent sibling combinator

Tags: html, css

Hi:) I'm trying to run the simplest example of :not(:placeholder-shown) and its not workings.Here is a link to my codepen. https://codepen.io/yael-screenovate/pen/eYJEqRB?editors=1100 what did i do wrong? thanx by advance. Heres the code:

```css
button {
  display: none;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown)+button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input/>
  <button>hi there</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. There is no placeholder shown and the button is shown. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Your example made my life so easy... regarding understanding this topic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you didn't set any `placeholder` attribute.

```css
button {
  display: none;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown)+button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="placeholder"/>
<button>hi there</button>
```

It makes more sense not to use the `:not` but do the whole logic the opposite:

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

input:placeholder-shown+button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="placeholder" />
<button>hi there</button>
```

Comment: This solution gave me an idea on how to solve a similar problem. I want to show the label of an field only if the field is focused or the placeholder is not shown. With the following it works with Tailwind.

```
input.peer
label.opacity-100 peer-placeholder-shown:opacity-0 peer-focus:opacity-100
```